# time series forecasting using support vector regression: underfitting

Tags: matlab, time-series, svm, forecasting

I have a time series dataset that consists of 60 datapoints. I have split up the dataset into two: the training (first 70% of data) and testing sets (last 30% of data). Using Matlab's fitrsvm function, I have built a support vector regression model on the training dataset and am trying to the predict the time series datapoints in the test dataset. I have The svr model approximates the training dataset pretty well. However, it doesn't even try to generalize the test dataset, it just seriously underfits the data i.e. gives a straight line without even going through any of the datapoints on the test dataset. Does anyone know why this happening? Is the dataset too small i.e. only 60 datapoints? Does it make sense to do cross validation? In my opinion it doesn't make sense to do cross validation as I am trying to forecast the last 30% of data. I have tried to change parameters etc but not helping.

Comment: Hi @N. Mathew did get anywhere with this? I have the same issue, are you using "predict" to do the forecast?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance in general: Have you tried making your time series stationary (via differencing or via power transform) or normalizing it before applying the SVR? These might help - they sometime help with NNets applied to time series.

---

Regarding CV: 
There are ways for doing cross validation for time series. First you could do a time series CV split (available in Python Scikit-learn and in R), I assume it will be there in Matlab as well.

```
[1, 2, 3],       [4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4],    [5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7].
```

This will work for any time series forecasting method.

But since you are using SVR, you can even use normal cross validation (which wouldn't work for something like ARIMA or Holt-Winters).

This is because recently, Bergmeir, Hyndman and Koo, have shown that for purely auto-regressive models, such as AR(p) models, Neural Networks, or Support Vector Regression, even normal CV can be used, as long as you format your training data so that it looks like a supervised machine learning problem instead of a time series problem.

To understand how this works, first you need to note that pure autoregressive method use only a fixed number of previous periods, so that instead of:

```
[1, 2, 3],          [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4],       [5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    [6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7]
```

You would have for example (for an order 3 (i.e. 3 lags) autoregressive model):

```
[1, 2, 3],   [4]
[2, 3, 4],   [5]
[3, 4, 5],   [6]
[4, 5, 6],   [7]
```

Then you need to think of your data in the ML format instead of the time series format:

```
[1, 2, 3 | 4]
[2, 3, 4 | 5]
[3, 4, 5 | 6]
[4, 5, 6 | 7]
```

So that that your data point is not just a single value like [4] but instead a vector with 3 inputs and one target value: 
    [1, 2, 3 | 4]

In this case, using normal cross validation (instead of time series cross validation) is valid, because dependence is no longer an issue, and you can train your model on:

```
[2, 3, 4 | 5]
[3, 4, 5 | 6]
[4, 5, 6 | 7]
```

And test with:

```
[1, 2, 3 | 4]
```

then train the model on:

```
[1, 2, 3 | 4]
[3, 4, 5 | 6]
[4, 5, 6 | 7]
```

And test with:

```
[2, 3, 4 | 5]
```

And so on....

See "A Note on the Validity of Cross-Validation for Evaluating Autoregressive Time Series Prediction", by Christoph Bergmeir, Rob J Hyndman, and Bonsoo Koob for details.